# how to access b2c sign in elements using javascript for UI customizing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i want to access b2c sign in page's h2, email and password elements to customize them.
using document.getElementsByClassName not giving any result

Answer (score 0):

B2C injects it the html inside the predefined div with id api (<div id="api>). You can read more on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#custom-html-and-css-overview). Now inorder to access the html elements injected by B2C inside the api div, you might have to check the structure of the html elements in the developer tools initially, and then try to select the specific element using javascript.

For eg: When B2C injects the html elements inside the api div, the section that contains the input tag for email looks like:
[image]

Now if you see, the input tag for email, doesn't contain any class there, rather if you check closely, you will find that each input element like for email or password is encapsulated under a parent div with class "entry-item". So in that case, the `document.getElementByClassName` would work on that level.

So to conclude, first identity the element you want to select using javascript using the dev tools on the browser, and then write the javascript accordingly.

In case the element you find doesn't contain any id or class, you can always use `document.querySelector` and select the tag to perform DOM manipulations.

Let me know if this works or if there are more queries around this.

Comment: thanks for your response @SouraMishra-MSFT, i know all the details you have explained and accessing different elements, but problem is occuring in changing only this text string "Sign in with your email address" i want to access its element and change the text.please tell the exact usage of document.querySelector for this

Comment: @MunazzaOsama, can you please share me the exact and complete HTML element. I can try once on my end and share my findings.

Comment: <form id="localAccountForm" action="JavaScript:void(0);" class="localAccount" aria-label="Sign in with your email address">
        <div class="intro">
          <h2 aria-level="1">
            Sign in with your email address
          </h2>
        </div>
       .....

Comment: @MunazzaOsama, just try this "let signInText = document.querySelectorAll(".intro h2");
  signInText[1].innerHTML = 'SignIn using email address';
  console.log(signInText[1]);"

Comment: @MunazzaOsama, I updated the existing string from "Sign in with your email address" to "SignIn using email address". Try this and let me know. This should help you in modifying the h2 item.

Comment: i tried :const signInText = document.querySelectorAll(".intro h2"); 
    alert( signInText.length);
    signInText[1].innerHTML = 'SignIn using email address'; 
    console.log(signInText[1]); and signInText.length returns 0.  samething was happen to me since many days of trying

Comment: @MunazzaOsama, just console.log signInText and check if you can see the returned array elements. In my case I had two elements, and the second element had the SignIn text. Check on your case which array element has that value and then try to extract it. It should work as it worked for me and gave me the response.